# Modify key="Value" config with sed

Tags: bash, sed, configuration-files

I am trying to write a script that configures a config file used by a nother script. I am trying to use sed like this

```
sed -c -i "s/\($TARGET_KEY *= *\).*/\1$REPLACEMENT_VALUE/" $CONFIG_FILE
```

But it's not working as it is intended to it strips the quotation marks and i cant figure out how to write it so it dont.

the second problem is that when i run this on Mac OS the out put is an error:

```
sed: illegal option -- c
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
   sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
```

I am new to usage of sed so please forgive my lack of skills in this area.

Comment: how is your config file looking like? one name=value pair per line? or could be more pairs in one line? also could the value be empty? e.g. in one line: `key1= key2=value2` ?

Comment: What should the `-c` option do? I do not see it in my sed (Linux) either.

Comment: @choroba : The -c option tells sed to copy the file when it shuffles it (instead of renaming) but it seems not to be a valid option no more.

Comment: @Kent like this one key="value" per line:

    Key1="value1"
    Key2="value2"
    Key3="value3"

only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the test below, I didn't add "-i", just print the output. you can add -i if you need:

```
kent$  cat c.conf 
key1="value1"
foo   =   "fooValue"
bar="barValue"

kent$  echo $k1
foo

kent$  echo $v1
foo_new

kent$  sed -r "s/($k1 *= *\").*/\1$v1\"/" c.conf
key1="value1"
foo   =   "foo_new"
bar="barValue"
```

Comment: Thanks @Kent. I am trying to modify this to skip commented lines (lines starting with `#`) but unable to figure out. Would you please help me ? I tried with `s/^\($k1\s*=\s*\).*$/\1$v1/ig` but not getting what I want.

Comment: The solution helped me, but i found mysterious ^M. To handle that final glitz is by:  sed -r "s/($k1 *= *\").*/\1$v1\"/;/\r/d" c.conf

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the quotes?  This works for me (on Cygwin):

```
~$ echo -e "key1=\"value1\"\nkey2=\"value2\""
key1="value1"
key2="value2"
~$ TARGET_KEY=key2
~$ REPLACEMENT_VALUE=new_val
~$ echo -e "key1=\"value1\"\nkey2=\"value2\"" | sed "s/\($TARGET_KEY *= *\"\).*/\1$REPLACEMENT_VALUE\"/"
key1="value1"
key2="new_val"
~$
```